# Gradle: How to map Lists from configuration-closure to extension settings

Tags: groovy, gradle-plugin

I have this (working) code, which is extended from the gradle documentation

https://docs.gradle.org/4.10.3/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:implementing_a_dsl

```
class User {
    String name
}


class Group {
    User user
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    String message
    final Group group

    @javax.inject.Inject
    GreetingPluginExtension(ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        group = objectFactory.newInstance(Group)
        group.user = objectFactory.newInstance(User)
    }

    void group(Action<? super Group> action) {
        action.execute(group)
    }

    void user(Action<? super User> action) {
        action.execute(group.user)
    }
}

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // Create the extension, passing in an ObjectFactory for it to use
        def extension = project.extensions.create('greeting', GreetingPluginExtension, project.objects)
        project.task('hello') {
            doLast {
                    println "${extension.message} from ${extension.group.user.name}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The configuration closure looks like this:

```
greeting {
    message = 'Hello'
    group {
        user {
            name = 'tom'
        }
    }
}
```

But I would like to have a List of users an I tried:

```
class User {
    String name
}


class Group {
    ArrayList<User> users
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    String message
    final Group group

    @javax.inject.Inject
    GreetingPluginExtension(ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        // Create a Person instance
        group = objectFactory.newInstance(Group)
        group.users = []
    }

    void group(Action<? super Group> action) {
        action.execute(group)
    }

    void users(Action<? super ArrayList<User>> action) {
        action.execute(group.users)
    }
}

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // Create the extension, passing in an ObjectFactory for it to use
        def extension = project.extensions.create('greeting', GreetingPluginExtension, project.objects)
        project.task('hello') {
            doLast {
                extension.group.users.each {

                    println "${extension.message} from ${it.name}"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

with this closure:

```
greeting {
    message = 'Hello'
    group {
        users = [
                {name = 'tom'} ,
                {name = 'tim'}
        ]
    }
}
```

my output is the following:

```
Hello from myProjectName
Hello from myProjectName
```

which is not the expected output but the rootProject.name
The output has the right number of elements, but is not referenced to the user.
How can I fix this? I would also appreciate informations about other approaches to map nested objects (and lists) into the extension-setting.

Greetings Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following slightly modified version I believe does what you intended:

```
apply plugin: GreetingPlugin

greeting {
    message = 'Hello'
    group {
      user(name: 'tom')
      user(name: 'tim')
    }
}


class User {
    String name
}

class Group {
    ArrayList<User> users = []

    def user(props) {
      users << new User(props)
    }
}

class GreetingPluginExtension {
    String message
    final Group group

    @javax.inject.Inject
    GreetingPluginExtension(ObjectFactory objectFactory) {
        // Create a Person instance
        group = objectFactory.newInstance(Group)
    }

    void group(Action<? super Group> action) {
        action.execute(group)
    }
}

class GreetingPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {
        // Create the extension, passing in an ObjectFactory for it to use
        def extension = project.extensions.create('greeting', GreetingPluginExtension, project.objects)
        project.task('hello') {
            doLast {
                extension.group.users.each {
                    println "${extension.message} from ${it.name}"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run, it prints:

```
~> gradle hello

> Task :hello
Hello from tom
Hello from tim

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Note that I have removed the method:

```
void users(Action<? super ArrayList<User>> action)
```

as it is not needed for the above to work. I also changed the dsl somewhat. I actually think the changed dsl looks more readable and idiomatic but this is of course a matter of taste.

Note also that if you want to send in more properties to the user (say `email`), you can do this without modifying the scaffolding code, i.e.:

```
greeting {
    message = 'Hello'
    group {
      user(name: 'tom', email: 'tom@wonderland.org')
      user(name: 'tim', email: 'tim@wonderland.org')
    }
}
class User {
    String name
    String email
}
```

If you were specifically looking for how you make a doubly nested configuration closure for a collection work, this does not solve your problem, but it does give you a reasonably clean way of accomplishing what the build script intended.

Comment: If you think this response answers your question, please consider accepting it:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers